# HotSpot LogCompilation output: Should V (Void) match a java.lang.Object return type?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Background: I'm the author of a HotSpot LogCompilation visualiser called [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) and I'm refactoring the parsing engine. I have a question on matching LogCompilation method signatures to `Class.getDeclaredMethod()` signatures, specifically about matching the void return type.

Given the HotSpot LogCompilation output snippet:

```
<nmethod compile_id='48' compile_kind='c2n' entry='0x00007f01fc3f41c0'
size='328' address='0x00007f01fc3f4090' relocation_offset='296' 
consts_offset='328' insts_offset='304' 
method='java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle linkToStatic 
(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/invoke/MemberName;)V' 
bytes='0' count='0' iicount='0' stamp='0.840'/>
```

Which indicates a compilation (using a native wrapper) of the method `linkToStatic` on class `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` which takes as parameters

`java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.invoke.MemberName` and returns `void`

The only method it could possibly match on `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` has signature:

```
static native java.lang.Object linkToStatic(java.lang.Object...) throws java.lang.Throwable;
```

Which has `java.lang.Object` varargs parameters (matches the LogCompilation parameters) but declares a `java.lang.Object` return type.

Is it legal to match the `void` return from the LogCompilation signature with `java.lang.Object` for the reason that:

```
Object.class.isAssignableFrom(Void.class); // returns true
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could explain the mechanics behind the void return type.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linkToStatic` method is a [signature polymorphic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9). Their signature varies depending on the call site.

HotSpot will internally create new `Method` objects with the signature required by a call site (see `SystemDictionary::find_method_handle_intrinsic`).

The `method` attribute you see for this `nmethod` is the string representation of such a `Method`: its signature (including the return type) is specialized to a specific call site.

So in general it is *not* ok to match the `void` return type with `java.lang.Object` and you probably need a special case to match signature polymorphic methods.

Comment: Thanks. I am now detecting for polymorphic signatures using `method.getAnnotations().getAnnotationType().getSimpleName();` and handling them as a special case.